# Avoid using named containers in docker when using jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, cassandra

I am using Jenkins to do builds and CI.

I have created a docker-compose file where it would require app:PHP-APP (with nginx inside), mysql, redis, and cassandra node.

In order for my tests to run - I need my keyspace and tables to be loaded. Therefore in my docker-compose file for CI specifically I have named my cassandra container cassandra_ext. If I don't then docker will self assign a random hash in front of it.

Then i would use `docker exec cassandra_ext cqlsh ...` to load the keyspace and the tables.

My test would turn green.

The problem is the following:

with the container_name specified - I can no longer mount another version of that exact container - therefore - when I have another similar test in a different branch being run - it will fail because my `docker-composer up -d` will state that another container of the same name is running already.

Is there a work around for this? Should I be doing something else in order to make the mounting of the cassandra node remain dynamic (similar to the redis / mysql) while able to do a docker exec/run to load the necessary tables.

*UPDATE*

here is my `docker-compose.ci.yml` file

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: app
    depends_on:
      - cassandra
  node:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: node
  redis:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: redis
  mysql:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASS}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USER}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASS}"
  cassandra:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: cassandra
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
    container_name: cassandra_ext
networks:
  shared_net:
    external:
      name: shared_net
volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: "local"
  redisdata:
    driver: "local"
  cassandradata:
    driver: "local"
```

here is the Jenkinsfile

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node('master') {
    try {
        stage('build') {
            checkout scm
            // Start services (Let docker-compose build containers for testing)
            sh "docker network create shared_net || true"
            sh "./develop.sh up -d"

            // Get composer dependencies
            sh "./develop.sh composer install"

            // Create .env file for testing
            sh 'cp .env.ci .env'
            sh './develop.sh art key:generate'
            sh './develop.sh art migrate'
            sleep 10
            sh 'docker logs --tail 10 cassandra_ext'
            sh 'docker cp $(pwd)/scripts cassandra_ext:/tmp'
            sh 'docker exec cassandra_ext cqlsh -f /tmp/scripts/cassandra_keyspace_travis.cql || true'
            sh 'docker exec cassandra_ext cqlsh -k test -f /tmp/scripts/cassandra_travis.cql || true'
        }
        stage('test') {
            sh "APP_ENV=testing ./develop.sh test"
        }
    } catch(error) {
        // Need to do something about alerts
        throw error
    } finally {
        // Spin down containers no matter what happens
        sh './develop.sh down'
    }
}
```

and the bash script `develop.sh` is from vessel: [https://github.com/shipping-docker/vessel/blob/master/docker-files/vessel]

and if I switch `docker exec` for the following i get a TTY error:

```
./develop.sh exec cassandra cqlsh -f /tmp/scripts/cassandra_keyspace_travis.cql
the input device is not a TTY
```

The bash script effective runs: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.yml` and at the end of the script it just passes the extra argument specified:

```
# Else, pass-thru args to docker-compose
else
    $COMPOSE "$@"
fi
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't `docker-compose exec` against the service name, removing the explicit name entry? (docker-compose will name the container based on the directory, but you can still reference it by the service meme with compose)

Comment: before starting the new container - you can start a command "docker-compose rm -f" to remove a container if it is available. and ignore the outcome (since it is possible that container might not be available), However if it is available - it will remove it.

Comment: @bto because when i tried that - i get a TTY error.

Comment: @fly2matrix my problem is when two concurrent test that uses the same container name collides. so if  you are telling me i should remove the container while its being used wont the first test fail?

Comment: If that is the case - you can have a docker-compose-test.yml and remove container-names out of it. And use this docker-compose-test.yml for your testing purpose.

Comment: Can you provide your `docker-compose.yml` entry for the `cassandra_ext` service, a sample of the "random hash" in front of the unnamed container, and the TTY error from the `docker-compose exec`? A [mcve] might be asking a bit much, but some additional detail on your specific configuration would be beneficial.

Comment: @bto done - updated. with references, jenkinsfile, docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

It's generally preferable to work with containers defined in a `docker-compose` YML file using `docker-compose` instead of dealing with the extra hassles and complications introduced by interacting with them using "plain" `docker` commands. It looks like the Vessel tool assists by providing the `develop.sh` script that adds some extra helper functionality.

However, you're running into an error going that route:

> `the input device is not a TTY`

There appears to be an open issue with docker-compose surrounding this specific error. Issue [5696](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5696) identifies problems with compose version `1.19.0` and greater where the reporter indicates this same error with even simple commands. Workaround recommended by shin-, a Docker member, is to set:

```
COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI=1
```

So for your `Jenkinsfile`, you could try to modify your cassandra_ext commands to be:

```
sh 'COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI=1 ./develop.sh exec cassandra_ext cqlsh -f /tmp/scripts/cassandra_keyspace_travis.cql || true'
sh 'COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI=1 ./develop.sh exec cassandra_ext cqlsh -k test -f /tmp/scripts/cassandra_travis.cql || true'
```

Or to make it a bit more blatant:

```
withEnv(["COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI=1"]){
    sh './develop.sh exec cassandra_ext cqlsh -f /tmp/scripts/cassandra_keyspace_travis.cql || true'
    sh './develop.sh exec cassandra_ext cqlsh -k test -f /tmp/scripts/cassandra_travis.cql || true'
}
```